# How do I resolve "Source not found while debugging in Eclipse"?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

How do I resolve "Source not found while debugging in Eclipse" messages?

I already clicked on "Edit Source Lookup Path" in Eclipse and add my project. but its not working for me. I am using Tomcat 6.0. Is any jar file I should include?

Answer (score -2):

You need to add application src folder in add luck up dilog box. so your application can find all the source clasee.